# Bubbles not appearing in scatter_geo python

Tags: python, plotly, scatter-plot, geo

```
query = '''SELECT country, state, count(puppies) as rich_pop FROM data group by state HAVING country=="United States"'''
 
df = sqldf(query)

fig = px.scatter_geo(df, locations="state", locationmode='USA-states', scope="usa", size="rich_pop", color='count')

fig.show()
```

The bubbles are not showing though I have 44 states of the US in my data. I don't understand what is the problem.

SOLVED: The abbreviations of the states names need to be in CAPITAL letters.

Comment: Is the location designation, State, a shortened abbreviation? If not, please change it to an abbreviation.

Comment: No it is not an abbreviation.
So instead of New York -> NY and so on, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either

Comment: Thank you so much. The abbreviations have to be in CAPITAL letters